# Do several aggregates in one query using where clause SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

Is it possible to do several aggregate functions inside a single query

I know whe can use

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01'
```

I've been trying to make an example

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (id varchar(10), value int, `date` date, situation varchar(10) ) ;

INSERT INTO mytable
    (id, value, date, situation)
VALUES
    ('id0', 1338, '2012-05-14','Urgent'),
    ('id0', 3572, '2012-05-13','Urgent'),
    ('id0', 3232, '2012-05-06','Urgent'),
    ('id0', 3068, '2012-05-05','Post'),
    ('id0', 3363, '2012-05-04','Urgent'),
    ('id0', 2022, '2012-04-28','Anual'),
    ('id0', 3193, '2012-04-24','Post')
```

But is it possible to use the same query to get other aggregate values?

```
SELECT SUM(value),SUM(value),Count(*) FROM mytable WHERE date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01', WHERE date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01', Where situation like 'Urgent'
```

instead of 3 queries:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01'
SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01'
SELECT Count(*)   FROM mytable Where situation like 'Urgent'
```

Comment: Do you really mean `date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01'`?  Or do you mean `date >= '2012-05-01' and date < '2012-10-01'`?  In the first version, 2012-10-01 is included in the calculations.  In the second, it is not.  (And the meaning of the first version would be different if you used `datetime` instead of `date`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use case

```
select
    sum(case when date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01' then value else 0 end) as sum1,
    sum(case when date between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01' then value else 0 end) as sum2,
    sum(case when situation like 'Urgent' then 1 else 0 end) as count1
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-06-01' THEN value ELSE 0 END)
as sum1,
SUM(CASE WHEN date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01' THEN value ELSE 0 END)
as sum2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN situation like 'Urgent%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
as cnt1
FROM mytable Where situation like 'Urgent%' OR  date  between '2012-05-01' AND '2012-10-01'
```

I guess you missed % in like : `like 'Urgent%'`, not `like 'Urgent'`.